# $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ has one maximal ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

My lecture notes state that the set $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$, defined as

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}:=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}\gcd(a,b)=1\text{ and } 2\nmid b\right\}$$ has a unique maximal ideal generated by $\left<2\right>$. Is this example trying to say that the set of even integers is the maximal ideal, and if so, why is this maximal. Can anyone prove that this is indeed a maximal ideal. Also in the set $\mathbb{Z}$, both $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are maximal ideals, but I thought a maximal ideal is an ideal which contains all other ideals.

Comment: A maximal ideal does not necessarily contain all other ideals. A maximal ideal cannot be contained in a proper ideal.

Comment: You can check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124032/maximal-ideal-in-local-ring/1124065#1124065 which was very similar in nature to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that of the complement of $2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ is $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}^{\times}$, showing thereby that $2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ is the *unique* maximal ideal of $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$. This show that $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ is a *local ring*.

"Alternatively", consider the "map" from $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ to $\mathbf{F}_2$ defined by sending an element $x= \frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b$ integers and $2$ not dividing $b$ to $\overline{a} \overline{b}^{-1}$, where $\overline{x}$ is the image in $\mathbf{F}_2$ of the integer $x$. Show that this map is well defined, that is, that it does not depend on the writing $x= \frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b$ integers and $2$ not dividing $b$, and that it is a ring morphism. Show that its kernel is the *[ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29)* $2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$. As this morphism is surjective, this implies passing to the quotient that the induced map $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)} / 2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)} \to \mathbf{F}_2$ is an isomorphism. As $\mathbf{F}_2$ is a field, this shows that $2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$.

*Intuition.* More generally instead of $2$, let $p$ be a prime. What is $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ ? The ring $\mathbf{Z}$ is a ring where only $\pm 1$ are invertible. We want to construct a bigger ring, containing $\mathbf{Z}$, and in which every guy from $\mathbf{Z}$ that is not divisible by $p$ will become invertible. This ring is $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$. (For any ring, $A^{\times}$ denotes the set of invertible elements of $A$.) Then, $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}^{\times} = \mathbf{Z}_{(p)} \backslash p\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$.

*Remark.* More generally, if $A$ is a commutative ring with unit and if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, with the same arguments, you have an isomorphism $A_{\mathfrak{p}} / \mathfrak{p} A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to \textrm{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$, where $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the *[localisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring)* of $A$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $S = A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ of $A$. The ring $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is also called by abuse of language the location of $A$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, or also more simply, the localization of $A$ a $\mathfrak{p}$. This vocabulary applies of course to $A = \mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{p} = 2 \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: just to clarify some of your notation, is $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}^x$ the group $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ closed under multiplacation

Comment: Also is there a name for this set $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$

Comment: @AndrewBrick No, $\mathbf{Z}$ is a ring where only $\pm$ are invertible. We want to construct a bigger ring, containing $\mathbf{Z}$, and in which every guy from $\mathbf{Z}$ that is not divisible by $2$ will become invertible. This ring is $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$. For any ring, $A^{\times}$ denotes the set of invertible elements of $A$. Then, $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}^{\times} = \mathbf{Z}_{(2)} \backslash 2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$.

Comment: @AndrewBrick As I said generally in the last paragraph of my answer, $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$ is called the localised of $\mathbf{Z}$ with respect to the multiplicative (that is, stable by multiplication) set $S = \mathbf{Z}\backslash 2\mathbf{Z}$. By abuse of notation, one calls it the localisation of $\mathbf{Z}$ at the prime ideal $2\mathbf{Z}$, or also simply the localization of $\mathbf{Z}$ at $2\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: so $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}^x=\{\frac{b}{a}\in\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}|\exists\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)} \}$

Comment: So in $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}^x$ neither numerator nor denominator can be divisible by 2, hence its the same set $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ excluding even numerator fractions

Comment: @AndrewBrick No, $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}^{times} = \{x\in\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}\;|\;\exists y\in\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}, xy = 1\}$, and then : $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)} = \{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbf{Q}\;|\;a,b\in\in\mathbf{Z},b\not=0,2\nmid b\}$ and then $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}^{\times} = \{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbf{Q}\;|\;a,b\in\in\mathbf{Z},b\not=0,2\nmid b, 2|a\}$.

Comment: Based on the two definitions you gave for $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}^x$, if $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}^x$, then $\exists y=\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$. $xy=1$, hence $x=\frac{b}{a}$, both $\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{a}\in \mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$, so both $a$ and $b$ aren't divisible by 2, but you said $a$ is divisible by 2

Comment: @AndrewBrick Yeah, I made a typo, sorry. (It's hard from a mobile phone...) Yes, $\mathbf{Z}_{(2)}^{\times} = \{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbf{Q}\;|\;a,b\in\mathbf{Z},b\not=0,2\nmid b, 2\nmid a\}$ obviously.

Comment: So the complement of the set of invertable elements in my set, is a maximal ideal, but I son't see how, I'm sorry if my questions seem trivial.

Comment: @AndrewBrick Np ! First, the complement is $2 \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$, that I not $I$ for short, so it's and ideal. Let's show that it is maximal. First of all, it is strict, as $1 \not\in I$. Second, let's $J$ a strict ideal of $A := \mathbf{Z}_{(2)}$. As $J$ is strict, it does not containt any element of $A^{\times}$, and this means that it is contained in the complement of $A^{\times}$ in $A$, and this is our ideal $I$. So $I$ is maximal indeed.

Comment: @AndrewBrick And this is general, if $A$ is a ring, then $A$ contains only one maximal if and only if $A \backslash A^{\times}$ is an ideal of $A$, in which case $A \backslash A^{\times}$ is this maximal ideal, and $A$ is called a local ring.

Comment: @AndrewBrick have a look at the chapter 2 (on localization) of http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-64239-8 which is a good reference for localization.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I'll read up on the chapter on localization

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ All odd primes are units so all nonunits are associates of $\,2^n,\,$ so all ideals can be generated by powers of $\,2,\,$ hence are principal, generated by their least power of $\,2;\,$ for example assuming $\,i\le j\le k\le \ldots\,$ then $\,(2^i,2^j,2^k,\ldots)\, =\, 2^i(1, 2^{j-i},2^{k-i},\ldots)\, =\, (2^i).$

Answer (score -1):

The maximal ideal is $2\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$.

Show it is maximal by showing that $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}/2\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ is a field.

To show that it is the only maximal ideal, there are many ways :

- Show that $J(\mathbb{Z}_{(2)})=2\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ where $J$ is the Jacobson ideal.
- Use the following theorem : If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then the following are equivalent :

(1) $R$ has a unique maximal ideal (such a ring is called *local*)

(2) $R\backslash M=R^{\times}$

(3) $\forall a,b\not\in R^{\times},a+b\not\in R^{\times}$.