# $I$ is maximal ideal $\implies$ $R/I$ has no proper ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm reading through a proof in a book on commutative algebra and in the proof it uses the fact that $I$ is a maximal ideal $\implies$ $R/I$ has no proper ideals, by using the correspondence theorem. I'm fairly new to the theory of ideals, so I don't see how the correspondence theorem can be applied to show this. The book doesn't go too much into this, so I'm sorry if this is a very basic concept. Also just to confirm, here the book is referring to the quotient group $R/I=\{a+I|a\in R\}$ and not something else I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting $\pi : R \to R/$ the quotient map, the ideals $J$ of $R/I$ are in increasing bijection with the ideals of $R$ containing $I$ via the the inverse image by $\pi$, namely, the map $J\mapsto \pi^{-1}(J)$ whose inverse is $K\mapsto \pi(K)$. As $I$ is maximal, you see that the only ideals of $A$ containing it are $I$ and $R$, which give the zero ideal and $R/I$.

Comment: what do you mean by "increasing bijection"?

Comment: @AndrewBrick That if $J\subseteq J'$ then $\pi^{-1}(J) \subseteq \pi^{-1}(J')$.

Comment: if $I$ is indeed maximal, then there is no ideal $I_2$, s.t $R\subset I_2\subset I$, where $R\neq I_2$ and $I_2\neq I$. Then clearly any ideal containing the maximal ideal $I$ must be $I$ or the whole ring $R$, Which in $R/I$ are the ideals $R/I$ and $\{0\}$

Comment: does this seem sufficient to prove my claim?

Comment: @AndrewBrick Yes, it is exactly what I wrote in my answer, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a\in R\setminus I$.  Since $I$ is maximal, $(a,I)=R$, therefore the ideal $(a,I)+I$ in $R/I$ must be all of $R/I$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $(a,I)$

Comment: $(a,I)$ is the ideal generated by $I\cup\{a\}$ or, in other words, the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $a$.

Comment: so $K(\alpha)$ is the field $K$ extended by including $\alpha$, $K[\alpha]$ is the ring $K$ extended by including $\alpha$ and $(a,I)$ is the ideal extended by including $\alpha$. I'm just curious about whether this notation is universal or if there's other notation by different authors I should look out for

Comment: @AndrewBrick I have the strange feeling that your are trying to understand some proofs (like local rings here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123892/mathbbz-2-has-one-maximal-ideal/1123905#1123905 ) stated at some point where you have to master a bit basic concepts (like what $(a,I)$ is, and what are ideals of quotient ring like here). I would advise to you to really work out all these concepts, and then to pass to something more hard, but not to do both at the same time, because if you do so, you will have difficulties.

Comment: @Andrew Brick. These notations are standard. It's been a while since I've done any reading in this area. So there may be notations of which I'm not aware